# RuntimeError when using copy.deepcopy to get QMenu.title() in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pyqt4, qmenu

I am trying to copy a dictionary (from another class / file) into a variable using `copy.deepcopy` so that the original dictionary contents will not be affected.

Initially, I was using `.copy()` which works in my cause, but turns out it actually affected the contents in the dictionary that I copied from.. Found out that `copy.deepcopy` is to be used instead but this time round, I am getting another error - `# RuntimeError: '__init__' method of object's base class (QMenu) not called.`

What I am trying to achieve here is to conform QMenu object naming (eg. QtGui.QMenu object at 0x7f142bd582d8) into human-readable form.

This is my code:

```
names_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.database.menus)
# This will affects content in self.database.menus
# names_copy = self.database.menus.copy()

# self.database.menus is of the following:
# defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {<QtGui.QMenu object at 0x7f142bd582d8>: ['Jack', 'Peter']}})

new_names_copy = {}
for k1, v1 in self.names_copy:
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():

       # Errors at the following line:
       # RuntimeError: '__init__' method of object's base class (QMenu) not called.
        names_copy[k1][k2] = names_copy[k1][k2]

        # Remove the dict of the QMenu object naming
        names_copy[k1].pop(k2)

print names_copy
# Expected Output: {0: {'Names': ['Jack', 'Peter']}})
```

Many thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: QMenu in C ++ does not have a Copy constructor (in general, no QObject has a copy constructor has it by design) so widgets can not be copied which is also reflected in Python

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for letting me know. Despite that being the case, wondering if you have any insights if you may have any alternative workarounds?

Comment: Provide an [MCVE], clearly explain what your bottom line is and maybe you have another alternative, I do not understand why you want to use deepcopy. why `names_copy[k1][k2] = names_copy[k1][k2]`?

Comment: @TehKi What is the *real* purpose of trying to copy these menu objects? What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? As it stands, your question looks very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please therefore edit your question and provide some realistic context so that people can see what kind of problem(s) you are trying to solve.